# WiX built-in WixUI Dialog Sets have horizontal lines that are just a little too short (picture included)

Tags: user-interface, deployment, wix, wix3.5

I am creating an installer for my program using WiX (Windows Installer XML). I have used the following code to begin using the built-in WixUI Dialog Sets:

```
<Product ...>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree" />
</Product>
```

This, however, creates a dialog set with horizontal lines that are just a little bit too short on every dialog as shown here:

[Wix Horizontal Lines Too Short http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/2421/wixhorizontallinestoosh.png](http://img156.imageshack.us/img156/2421/wixhorizontallinestoosh.png)

I understand that I could create my own set of dialogs to use instead by using software such as [SharpSetup](http://sharpsetup.eu/) and [WixEdit](http://wixedit.sourceforge.net/) but I like the dialogs that WiX creates and only want to make a very small change to them.

Is my best option to download the WiX source code and try to modify it? Is there a more simple solution? Perhaps I should contact the developers of WiX to list it as a bug? Maybe they like it that way though. I however think it looks out of place and would like to change it.

I am using the latest weekly release of WiX 3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a reasonable bug to open. I never noticed before. A fix will require updating the original source.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I have listed this as a bug.

Comment: @Coder7862396: I've noticed this bug is still present in the newest WiX (version Jan 31 2011). Could you please provide a link to your bug report, so I can see its status? Thanks.

Comment: @Paya Here's the link (I know it's been 10 years but the bug still exists): https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/2691